# How to make a recursive menu in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following html which corresponds to a navbar sidebar in html.

I tried the following tutorial but I could not find the desired idea:

https://www.ozkary.com/2017/06/angular2-navigation-menu-with-recursive.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <img src="assets/images/test_img.png" >   
            <p>Lucia Pérez</p>
            <p>Admin</p>
        </div>

        <ul class="seccion-menu-dropdown">
            <li class="active">
                <span class="material-icons"> account_box</span> <a href="#asivamos" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Así Vamos</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="asivamos">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">asivamos 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">asivamos 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">asivamos 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="material-icons"> account_box</span><a href="#pacientes" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pacientes</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pacientes">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">pacientes 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">pacientes 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">pacientes 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="material-icons"> account_box</span><a href="#escalas" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Escalas</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="escalas">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Escalas 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Escalas 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Escalas 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="material-icons"> account_box</span><a href="#tromboprofilaxis" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Trombo<br/>Efectiva</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="tromboprofilaxis">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">tromboprofilaxis 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">tromboprofilaxis 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">tromboprofilaxis 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="menu-final">
            <li><span class="material-icons"> account_box</span>Ayuda y Soporte</li>
            <li><span class="material-icons"> account_box</span>Cerrar Sesión</li>
            <li><span class="material-icons"> account_box</span>Terminos Legales</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
```

But I would like to know how to turn it into a recursive menu, but I don't understand very well the idea of recursion and how to do it in this aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted tutorial link is well describing how you can achieve the goal of recursive structure for your case.

The recurcion is build with the nested 'IMenu' object, which holds all needed menu entries.

To display the recursive object, the component uses a ng-template for each single menu item. To render the sub items, the template has a nested ng-container which also uses the ng-template. With this you can nest your component structure.

So you can control your structure by defining a IMenu-object in the compontent's ts-file.